# push an element to an array in a mongoose document

Tags: mongoose, chat, database-schema

My schema is as follows:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
_id: String,
name:String,
to:[{
   name: String,
   message: [{
      content: String
      timestamp: Date
            }]
   }]
});
```

I need to push the `{content: Content, timeStamp: timestamp}` to the `message` array where `to.name == "someName"`.

I tried in this way but could not succeed.Please help me.

```
User
  .find({_id: id})
  .where('to.name').equals("someName")
  .to.message.push({content: Content, timeStamp: timestamp})
  .exec(function(err, doc){
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(doc);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `update` that uses the `$push` operator:

```js
User.update(
  {_id: id, 'to.name': 'someName'},
  {$push: {'to.$.message': {content: Content, timeStamp: timestamp}}},
  function(err, numAffected) { ... }
);
```

The positional `$` operator is used to reference the index of the `to` element matched by the query.